# tests fail when executing using Github-actions dotnet 5 on linux

Tags: github, .net-core, github-actions

there is solution which consists of two dotnet5 projects: API and Unit tests.
when I run unit tests locally, everything works fine. I publish the test project and then run tests using windows power shell from the publish directory. All tests pass, no errors.

Then, when trying to execute tests using github-actions for CI/CD pipeline, some tests (which are using `WebApplicationFactory`) fail with following error:

```
2021-06-08T16:37:11.1642123Z   Failed testname [269 ms]
2021-06-08T16:37:11.1646886Z   Error Message:
2021-06-08T16:37:11.1653209Z    Unable to create instance of class Path.to.class. Error: System.InvalidOperationException: Solution root could not be located using application root long/path/to/publish/..
2021-06-08T16:37:11.1658519Z   Stack Trace:
2021-06-08T16:37:11.1693810Z       at Microsoft.AspNetCore.TestHost.WebHostBuilderExtensions.UseSolutionRelativeContentRoot(IWebHostBuilder builder, String solutionRelativePath, String applicationBasePath, String solutionName)
2021-06-08T16:37:11.1698072Z    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Testing.WebApplicationFactory`1.SetContentRoot(IWebHostBuilder builder)
2021-06-08T16:37:11.1701361Z    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Testing.WebApplicationFactory`1.<EnsureServer>b__20_0(IWebHostBuilder webHostBuilder)
2021-06-08T16:37:11.1705047Z    at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.GenericHostWebHostBuilderExtensions.ConfigureWebHost(IHostBuilder builder, Action`1 configure, Action`1 configureWebHostBuilder)
2021-06-08T16:37:11.1709799Z    at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.GenericHostWebHostBuilderExtensions.ConfigureWebHost(IHostBuilder builder, Action`1 configure)
2021-06-08T16:37:11.1712749Z    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Testing.WebApplicationFactory`1.EnsureServer()
2021-06-08T16:37:11.1714990Z    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Testing.WebApplicationFactory`1.CreateDefaultClient(DelegatingHandler[] handlers)
2021-06-08T16:37:11.1717851Z    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Testing.WebApplicationFactory`1.CreateDefaultClient(Uri baseAddress, DelegatingHandler[] handlers)
2021-06-08T16:37:11.1720757Z    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Testing.WebApplicationFactory`1.CreateClient(WebApplicationFactoryClientOptions options)
2021-06-08T16:37:11.1723155Z    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Testing.WebApplicationFactory`1.CreateClient()
```

any thoughts?

P.S.
the only difference that I noticed is the `Microsoft (R) Test Execution Command Line Tool` Version, which in case of github actions equals to `16.10.0` and locally I have version `16.9.4`

github actions pipeline.yaml file:

```
name: Pipeline
on:
  workflow_dispatch:
  push:
    branches:
      - develop
      - master
      - main
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - develop
      - master
      - main
defaults:
  run:
    shell: pwsh
env:
  DOTNET_NOLOGO: true
  ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT: Development
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v1
        with:
          dotnet-version: "5.0.x"
          source-url: https://nuget.pkg.github.com/company/index.json
          owner: company-builduser
        env:
          NUGET_AUTH_TOKEN: ${{secrets.COMPANY_TOKEN}}
      - name: "Cache: NuGet"
        id: cache-nuget
        uses: actions/cache@v2
        with:
          key: NuGet ${{hashFiles('**/*.csproj')}}
          path: ~/.nuget/packages
      - run: dotnet publish -c Release Project.Web.Api.sln
      - name: "Cache: API"
        uses: actions/cache@v2
        with:
          key: Cache ${{github.run_number}} | Api
          path: |
            Project.Web.Api/bin/Release/net5.0/publish/*
            Dockerfile
      - name: "Cache: Unit tests"
        uses: actions/cache@v2
        with:
          key: Cache ${{github.run_number}} | Unit Tests
          path: |
            Project.Web.*.Tests/bin/Release/net5.0/publish/*
  unit-test:
    needs: build
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: "Get Cache: Unit tests"
        uses: actions/cache@v2
        with:
          key: Cache ${{github.run_number}} | Unit Tests
          path: Project.Web.*.Tests/bin/Release/net5.0/publish/*
      - uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v1
        with:
          dotnet-version: "5.0.x"
      - run: Get-ChildItem -Recurse *.Tests.dll | % { dotnet test $_ }
```

Comment: Could you share the github action workflow `.yml` implementation used in the question please?

Comment: @GuiFalourd the post is updated with corresponding information

Comment: The workflow looks ok. So I believe it might be related to your .NET project. I don't have experience in this language to help you much with this, but could it be related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54495319/xunit-invalidoperationexception-solution-root-could-not-be-located-using-app) or [this post](https://anthonygiretti.com/2021/04/16/testserver-asp-net-core-5-fix-system-invalidoperationexception-solution-root-could-not-be-located-using-application-root-with-a-custom-startup-file/)?